# What is the meaning of this message in bash commandline?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, gnome

I did

```
        gnome-open document.pdf
```

on my bash shell and I getting this following message :-

```
" ** (evince:11832): WARNING **: Error setting file metadata: No such file or directory"
```

What is wrong? I am not sure that this is it at all related to telnet? What should I do to so that it does not appear next time?

Comment: evince is a document viewer. what command are you running before you recieve the message? please be exact. Also, do you have the Adobe Acrobat PDF reader installed? that can mess with Evince: http://askubuntu.com/questions/232088/pdfs-dont-open

Comment: Oh so this has to do with documentviewer programme?

Comment: You mention telnet.  Are you trying to open this file over a telnet connection?  Because evince (and gnome for that matter) rely on an X Window session, which is inaccessible over telnet.  If you need to do it remotely, you can look into X11 forwarding over SSH with an SSH client such as Putty.

Comment: Sorry I was doing telnet but not to access the document remotely,but  earlier I was doing gnome-open document.pdf,which now I think could have caused this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common `evince` bug on most Linux distributions, and can be safely ignored (unless you are a developer and wants to fix this bug, then please do it!). But I'm sorry that I don't know the exact cause.

It has been reported elsewhere too:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691412

Comment: Would love to fix this bug!!!

Comment: It looks like it's been fixed (that bugzilla link has it marked as "resolved").  There's a good chance updating it to the latest version will solve your issues.  Depends on distro though.

Comment: But by looking at the comment in that bug, it seems the the bug was just closed because it was too old and no one cared to look at it. So, the resolution RESOLVED/FIXED seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Probably any progress on this will be recorded at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771351 , the upstream bug ticket.

Comment: Huh, say what, come again???